# Github: Remote does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: git, github, git-fetch

I'm having some trouble with Github throwing the error: fatal: 'remote' does not appear to be a git repository.

I did the cloning, which was successful.

```
git clone https://github.com/StephenW789/CIS-41B-Final-Project-Public

cd CIS-41B-Final-Project-Public

git remote -v # Prints out the correct origin as expected
```

I then did this, which ended up having the error message

```
git fetch remote main
fatal: 'remote' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I tried the following, but the issue still persists.

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add https://github.com/StephenW789/CIS-41B-Final-Project-Public
git fetch remote main
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try `https://github.com/StephenW789/CIS-41B-Final-Project-Public.git`, you shouldn't be using the url to the web presentation of your repository, you should use the clone url provided by github instead. The web address works in some cases, but not in all, as you've discovered.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `remote` is not the name of the remote: `origin` is the name of the remote.  That is: instead of `git fetch remote` you want `git fetch origin`.

I, like Lasse V. Karlsen and yourself, missed this on the first few read-throughs.  It's very easy to read "remote" as the correct name of the remote. :-)

Comment: You're right, I completely missed that :)